# Embedded Videos on other sites are working, but not on my (Django)

Tags: python, html, css, django, youtube

so i try to embed youtube videos on my website: http://mario3011.pythonanywhere.com/video (looks bad i know) and i doesnt work. It always says Video is not available. But if i check on this site: [http://mesdomaines.nu/eendracht/youtube_embedding_check/youtube_embedding_check.html#:~:text=The%20only%20sure%20way%20to,video%20can't%20be%20embedded](http://mesdomaines.nu/eendracht/youtube_embedding_check/youtube_embedding_check.html#:%7E:text=The%20only%20sure%20way%20to,video%20can%27t%20be%20embedded) the videos i wanna embed are workin?
so what am i doing wrong?

This is the code:
`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{ obj.0 }}" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen>{{obj.0}}</iframe>`

and this is another version with the django-embed-video api:
`{% video obj.1 '940x705' %}`

EDIT:
wbsite where its working: https://jsfiddle.net/srq643t9/21/

My Template Code

```
<style>
.row{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
.video{
    position:relative;
    margin:10px auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
.vote{
    position:relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10px 445px;
}



</style>
<body>
    {% load embed_video_tags %}
    {% if winner %}
        <div class="video">{% video obj.0 '940x705' %}</div>
    <form method="POST">
        {%csrf_token%}
        <input type="submit" name="reset" class="vote">
    </form>
    {% else %}
    {{ obj.0 }}
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfJYHfrOGgQ" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen>{{obj.0}}</iframe>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="video"></iframe></div>
        <div class="video">{% video obj.1 '940x705' %}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <form method="POST" class="video left">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type=submit name="1" class="vote">
        </form>

        <form method="POST" class="video right">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type=submit name="2" class="vote">
        </form>
    </div>
     <form method="POST">
        {%csrf_token%}
        <input type="submit" value="reset" class="vote">
    </form>
    {% endif %}

</body>
```

Comment: other site means which site. paste your django template code here

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser's developer console?  To access it in Chrome, go to the "hamburger" menu, then "More tools", then "Developer tools" and then click the "Console" tab on the pane that appears.

Comment: thanks, thats a good point. found this one: 

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://youtube.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.